# How can I calculate the Y position on a color slider, given an array of RGB values

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

I currently render a colour slider gradient onto a canvas element with the following code:

```
 var colorgrad = self.cache.colorctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, self.cache.colorpicker.height);
        colorgrad.addColorStop(0, 'red'); //red
        colorgrad.addColorStop(1 / 6, 'yellow'); //yellow
        colorgrad.addColorStop(2 / 6, 'lime') // green
        colorgrad.addColorStop(3 / 6, 'aqua'); // aqua
        colorgrad.addColorStop(4 / 6, 'blue'); //blue
        colorgrad.addColorStop(5 / 6, 'magenta'); // pink
        colorgrad.addColorStop(1, 'red'); //red
        self.cache.colorctx.fillStyle = colorgrad;
        self.cache.colorctx.fillRect(0, 0, 60, self.cache.colorpicker.height);

        self.cache.colourdata = self.cache.colorctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, self.cache.colorpicker.height).data;
```

This creates a gradient which draws all the way from through the colour wheel from red back to red and produces the image as follows:

[image]

When a user moves the circular controller at the top of the image I check the `Y` position of the controller against the cached image pixel data producing a simple colour picker which returns hex/RGB values.

So now that I have colour extraction working based on user input I also need to be able to take a hex colour value and work out the `top` value of the control.  So in essence, reverse the technique.  But I cannot seem to get my head around the correct algorithm to use.

I have a working `hex to RGB` function so the colour input can be considered an array of rgb values :

```
colour : {
        r : 255,
        g : 255,
        b : 255
}
```

So to summarise, when knowing the pixel height of the image above, how can I calculate the **y** position of a given colour in this image when provided with an array of RGB values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could convert the color to [`HSV`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). `H` will then represent the color as a value ranging from 0° (top in your picture) to 360° (bottom in your picture). With this you can calculate the position.

Comment: @Andreas Of course! I can't believe I didn't think of that! Thats the only push I need to get me to a working function so if you'd like to write your comment up as an answer I will award it to you.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the rgb color to [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) which will provide you with a color value (`H`) ranging from 0° (top of your slider) to 360° (bottom of your slider).
With that you can calculate the y position according to the size of the slider `(height / 360 * H)`